# Pass parameter to Angular 4 directive on input

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an input text field like this

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  [inputTextFilter]="A" [ngModel]="name">
```

and my directive is:

```
import { Directive, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inputTextFilter]'
})

export class InputTextFilterDirective {
  @Input('inputTextFilter') params: string;

  @HostListener('keypress', ['$event'])
  onKeyUp(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    console.log('got parameters: '+this.params);
  }
}
```

and I have created a Directive called "inputTextFilter" to which I want to pass the "A" parameter.  My passed parameter always shows as undefined.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Try this.

### Update:

```
import {Directive, SimpleChanges} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[inputTextFilter]'
})
export class MyDirective {
  @Input('inputTextFilter') params: string;
  constructor(){}
  ngOnInit(){
     console.log(this.params)
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that format is depricated, but I used @Input('inputTextFilter') params: string; and params is undefined

Comment: Where did you try to fetch params and is it defined in the first place in the input tag

Comment: It still prints Undefined

Comment: [inputTextFilter]="A" if A i a variable and inputTextFilter="A" if "A" is a string

Answer (score 5):

In the hope that this helps someone else...the problem is in the template.

When I pass the input as [myDirective]="A" the A is being intpreted as an undefined variable.  Since I wanted to pass the letter A I should have said [myDirective]="'A'"

Comment: @yurzui Please mark this as the answer. I would want to upvote it. Seems like it was all a working code and TSG is sending string into directive rather than a variable

Answer (score 3):

Try like this in directive :

```
import {Directive, Input, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[inputTextFilter]'
})
class FocusDirective {
    @Input() inputTextFilter: any;
    protected ngOnChanges() {
         console.log('inputTextFilter', this.inputTextFilter);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've added my directive code in the original question.  Looks almost identical to what you have, but params is always undefined.